# monitor tree with systemd path unit and pass parameter to service

Tags: recursion, path, systemd, subdirectory

With systemd path units, is it possible to monitor, not just a single directory or file, but recursively monitor all sub directories within a directory without explicitly listing each one? I tried wild cards but they didn't work even though the docs make mention of wildcard expansion. I'm finding .path units to be of extremely limited value.

mysolution.path

```
[Unit]
Description="File monitor path unit"

[Path]
DirectoryNotEmpty=/var/opt/mysolution
#DirectoryNotEmpty=/var/opt/mysolution/*
#PathChanged=/var/opt/mysolution/*/*
#PathChanged=/var/opt/mysolution/subdir

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The commented out lines are the ones that did not work at all

mysolution.service

```
[Unit]
Description="File monitor service unit"

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/chmod -fR ug+rw /var/opt/mysolution/subdir
#ExecStart=/bin/chmod -fR ug+rw /var/opt/mysolution/*
# I don't want to change permissions on mysolution, just all files and dirs under that directory

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Is it even possible to do this? I really don't want to have to manually maintain each individual directory and file that has to be monitored. I really only need to be notified of new files in any sub-directory of the /var/opt/mysolution/* directories. Can systemd do that without having to turn into some kind of hack?

Also, once a new file does show up, it would be nice to pass that to the corresponding service. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Hi @Vector, did you find any solution to the new file name problem?

Comment: No, sadly I have not. This seams to be a serious limitation of systemd path units. You're better off scripting your own using some of the inotify utilities that are out there and/or rolling your own with the inotify API. I'd post on the systemd list or suggest it to Lennart Poettering but he has such a horribly abrasive personality that I'm discouraged from even attempting it. He would probably tell me I'm a complete moron for even thinking I need such a thing, dismiss it as unnecessary, and try to convince me I never needed it anyway, all without  bothering to understand the problem.

Comment: In the meantime, I've discovered a relevant thread on GitHub and posted a comment... Let's see! https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/9066#issuecomment-401003217

Comment: As of currently, it seems still impossible. The issue you linked above seemed to care to a different aspect of the API, and it is closed now. The latest progress I saw upstream regarding this feature request, is here: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/4246#issuecomment-925668957 .